# Modify/hook into admin page of rate module

Tags: 7, hooks, rating

I'm creating a new widget type for the [rate module](http://drupal.org/project/rate) with some custom settings. I plan to use multiple instances of the same widget each with different custom settings. Is it possible to hook into `rate_widget_form` to alter the admin page of the rate module ?

**Example :**

```
admin/structure/rate/add?template=widgetname
admin/structure/rate/%/edit
```

**Sample Image :**

[image: Rate module custom settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. I used [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

```
function hook_form_rate_widget_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){ 
enter code here...
}
```